# C# COM-Interop dll for C++ COM dll doesn't work between 2 solutions

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, interop

I am trying to reuse an interop DLL that compiled in one project on another, and it doesn't work.

I'll elaborate:

- I compile the C++ COM DLL native_com_object.dll
- In the same solution I have a C# project called LocalComClient.dll that generates Interop.native_com_objectLib.dll to use the C++ native_com_object.dll.
- Last, I have **another solution** with a C# project (being compiled on another computer) called RemoteComClient.dll that references to native_com_object.dll (registered in that computer). This generates another Interop.native_com_objectLib.dll.

The problem is RemoteComClient.dll tries to load native_com_object.dll it **MUST** use its own Interop. If I try to use the LocalComClient.dll Interop .Net fails to load the assembly.

**Edit:** The exact exception message I am getting is:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.native_com_objectLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Of course the problem also occurs vice-versa (LocalComClient cannot use RemoteComClient's Interop).

My first question is - why?? As far as I understand it should generate the same interop (which obviously I am wrong).

My second question is, is it possible to make one interop for all the .Net clients of the DLL?

I'll point out I am using VS2013 (both machines), the C# objects are AnyCPU, and the C++ is x64.

**Important EDIT**: I cannot embed interop types because the C# projects are .Net 3.5 (not 4).

Comment: After register C++ dll and add reference to C# reference. Then did you make Embed Interop Types propert set as False?...

Comment: @VeeramaniBala - I am using .net 3.5, and I can't upgrade that to 4.0

Comment: The question uses "doesn't work" and "fails" far too often.  Document *exactly* what goes wrong, at a minimum an exception message and a stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant - You're absolutely right! Added the exception I am getting.

Comment: Just google the exception message, "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".  Sixty-five thousands hits, the top two are SO posts, you don't need another one.

Comment: @HansPassant, these posts doesn't answer my question. Its quite clear why these cases don't work. In the case I am talking about I am referencing COM, and the generated assembly has the same full name on both machines (unlike the posts from google).

Comment: The most obvious mismatch is that the version number is not the same.  Standard DLL Hell problem.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to see it for yourself.

Comment: The version number in both is 1.0.0.0, but I did not check yet in Fuslogvw.exe, I'll check it out!

Comment: @HansPassant - You're right! The local project has a strong name while the remote doesn't and its "moving" to the interop! Can you please write an answer so I can mark it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Very common exception message, the DLL it finds at runtime isn't the same as the reference assembly your program was compiled with.  A very basic DLL Hell problem, not otherwise specific to COM interop.

You diagnose these kind of failures with Fuslogvw.exe, its trace for the failed assembly bind shows you what it looked for and what it found.  The usual mismatch is the version number, you compiled your program with the 1.0.0.0 version of the interop assembly.  That version is generated from the type library version number of the COM server.  You were using version 1.0, kaboom if the COM server changed and you use its newer interop assembly.

And the PublicKeyToken can easily be a mismatch, you expect the interop DLL not to have one.  Kaboom if the one you load at runtime does have one.  Not terribly uncommon in COM interop, you tend to favor them getting stored in the GAC and that requires a strong name.  Something you usually do later, forgetting to rebuild the app is an easy mistake.

The solution is to rebuild the client app with the correct interop assembly.